# What do I need to do to make a field in SOLR sortable?

Tags: sorting, solr, lucene, xsd, solr-schema

I have a field called "title"

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" omitNorms="false"/>
```

Here is the file definition:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
 <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I make my query and try to sort by the [title] field.  the log says:

```
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select/ params={sort=title+asc&start=0&q="course"&wt=json&rows=15&version=2.2indent%3Don} hits=244 status=0 QTime=1
```

Which means my syntax is probably correct:

```
q="course"&amp;start=0&amp;rows=15&amp;version=2.2indent=true&amp;wt=json&amp;sort=Title%2Basc&sort=title+asc
```

The problem is, results do not come back sorted by the [title] field. I think I am missing something in the schema.xml file, but what?

Comment: What you mean when saying "to sort by title"? You can sort by date (e.g. latest first), by number (e.g. largest first) or alphabetically (characters one by one, taking into account unicode characters). And how want to sort multiword title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can sort on any field that is single-valued (*i.e.*, **not** tokenized (unless it uses an analyzer that produces a single term) **nor** multi-valued) and is indexed. So `text` and `text_*` fields are right out for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:
The field you are sorting by, should not be "too" tokenized...
[I followed this article which solved my problem.](http://solr.pl/en/2011/01/31/car-sale-application-schema-xml-designing-to-gain-what-we-really-need-part-1/)